# How do I build a 4-bit synchronous direct counter using only D Flip-Flops?

Tags: flipflop, counter

I have to build a counter using only D Flip-Flops and wires. What's the approach?

Comment: Are you sure your prof said "D" and not "T" FF's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D Flip-Flops are great for applications like counters because they "remember" their own states. They are sequential based components instead of combinational.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, for each bit, a D Flip-Flop is required.

NOT Q loops back to D; the CLK goes to the LOAD of the first Flip-Flop. Q goes to the bit counter and to the LOAD of the next Flip-Flop in the sequence.

How it works is this:

The counter is cleared. CLK goes high, the output of Q is '0' so the output of NOT Q is '1'. Since NOT Q is connected to D, the Flip-Flop gets loaded with '1'. The output of Q is now '1'. '1' is to LOAD the next Flip-Flop and the process simply continues.

Comment: That's fine if he doesn't need a synchronous counter.

Comment: From my understanding; I believe synchronous counters will require extra logic.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be a mismatch between the "synchronous" and "no gates" requirements. I would do some reading about Gray codes before I gave up altogether, but even that looks like a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

The key to your homework question is "Build a 4-bit synchronous **direct** counter using ONLY D Flip-Flops and wires."  note: **emphasis** mine.

This might be solved using either a "one hot" or a "thermometer code" style counter, which are sometimes used in FPGA designs.  Not the most efficient use of the FF's as there would be one FF per state but it meets the criteria.

Comment: I think this is the idea the question was getting at, a [ring counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter) of some sort. I think the twisted ring counter might be best solution, as one hot needs loading initially. +1

Comment: @OliGlaser it is unusual language, it is at best a guess.

Comment: I think it's a very good guess, the only elegant solution I can think of to the problem as worded. Judging by the accepted answer, it seems the OP has gone for a ripple counter being acceptable though, which puzzles me (maybe the question was wrong after all?)

Comment: @OliGlaser I had written 'usual" instead of the intended "unusual, since fixed.  Thinking about it more, one could represent higher "bit density" by inverting from each FF to the next /Q to D or Q to D.  It won't give you \$2^N\$ but I haven't thought this through fully, so I may be wrong.

Comment: I think one, one-hot ring counter for each bit (e.g. an 8 bit for the MSB, 4 for next, etc) would work for binary.